# PHP getting percentage from values

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, percentage

I am trying to get the percentage from 2 values so I can calc how far along the download is.

I have:

```
$downloaded = (int) 8035500032;
$filesize = (int) 26933586356;
```

How can I get the % these values? I am expecting ~ 34.7% based on those 2 values.

I tried the following with no accurate result

```
$progress = round(($filesize / $downloaded) * 100, 2);
$progress = ($downloaded / $filesize) * 100;
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: 8035500032/26933586356 = 0.2983449706915815 . 
why do you want to result is `34.7% `

Comment: Your final line is correct. `$progress = ($downloaded / $filesize) * 100;`

Comment: Both values exceed the 32 bit range (even unsigned) and will overflow on a 32bit machine.